# SQL to average different time scopes

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb

I have a table (DTP) with a simple structure and around 200k rows

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| DT    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PWR   | decimal(5,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Pix   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

- DT = a date-time every 10 minutes (of daylight)
- PWR = kW power generation avg for the 10 minute period

I want to know **daily, weekly, monthly and annual average power generation**

I suspected the following was wrong even before I tried it but I can't find help on how to structure my SQL to return these averages. (I'm anticipating one different query for each average per period.

```
SELECT AVG(PWR) AS DailyAvgPwr
FROM DTP 
WHERE (year(DT) AND month(DT) AND day(DT)) IN(
    SELECT PWR, year(DT), month(DT), day(DT)
    FROM DTP
    GROUP BY year(DT), month(DT), day(DT)
    ORDER BY year(DT), month(DT), day(DT);
```

It would be great to have some guidance on at least one of the periods: I'm guessing I can extrapolate the answer to get the other period averages.

[in case it's relevant, I'm using MariaDB, Server version: 10.5.12]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a job for [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).  Try something like this.

```
SELECT YEAR(DT) YR, MONTH(DT) mon, DAY(DT) dy,
       AVG(PWR) kW
  FROM DTP
 GROUP BY YEAR(DT), MONTH(DT), DAY(DT) WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Perfect. I'd never heard of 'WITH ROLLUP' before. Thanks